# using ADO.Net in access/datasheet query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

I am trying to understand a couple concepts with ADO.net and access. I understand how to query a table or set a record using ADO, and I have looked at various online articles pertaining to pulling tables and handling queries.  I am wondering what the relationship is between VBA Forms, DataSheets and Tables.

Am I to understand that a UserForm can contains a DataSheet? And is that essentially a table but seperate? Changing from "Form View" to "DataSheet View" shows me the information being logged in the form.  Yet, sorting the navigation view by "TABLE" will not bring up the same information as is logged into the DataSheet.

How would ADO access information from within a DataSheet object and not necessarily a table?  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: A datasheet is a form containing data from a table or query and only available within an instance of MS Access. A form can contain another form (subform). I doubt that a datasheet is relevant to ado.net

Comment: @Remou thanks for the response. So if I want access to that information, I should somehow export it into a table that can be accessed, and design the front end? is that a correct assumption? As well, would you recommend the access split database as far as reliability, or coding in ADO.net with your own program, achieving a similar result?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? A datasheet is based on a table or query, there should be no need to export anything. If you are using ADO.net, strictly speaking, you are not using MS Access, you are using the Jet/ACE database. It is nearly always best to split an Access application. Apart from safety reasons, it does help to heep clear in peoples' minds that there are two completely different parts to an Access application -- forms, code, etc, and a database, often Jet/ACE, but not always.

Comment: @Remou I am inheriting a database with access and trying to understand some of the features, and how best to improve it. As of right now the DB contains forms, queries, tables, all in one MDB file. I think designing a new UI in vb.net and keeping the DB strictly "back end" will be better in terms of customizability and integration with other systems for the future. I just was not sure how data sheets come into the mix. It appears that some of them exist under "query".  Is this ALWAYS the case with datasheets? They must exist with a record source relative to a table or query?

Comment: A datasheet is a form. You can remove the Record Source altogether, you will still have a form. It is not uncommon to set the recordsource  of a form at runtime.

Comment: Access can work very well indeed in a number of situations. Do not be put off by bad press. The only reason to change is that the current set-up is not working -- because it has grown too big, because the company has grown too big, etc. Even some of these cases can be dealt with by keeping the (working) front-end and replacing the back-end (database) with something more robust. For the most part, problems with Access are not do do with the front-end but to do with the small-office sized database that is Jet/ACE.

Comment: @Remou thanks for your insight.  If you would like to leave the above as an answer, I will mark it for credit. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A datasheet is a form. You can remove the Record Source altogether, you will still have a form. It is not uncommon to set the recordsource property of a form at runtime.

Access can work very well indeed in a number of situations. Do not be put off by bad press. The only reason to change is that the current set-up is not working -- because it has grown too big, because the company has grown too big, etc. Even some of these cases can be dealt with by keeping the (working) front-end and replacing the back-end (database) with something more robust. For the most part, problems with Access are not do do with the front-end but to do with the small-office sized database that is Jet/ACE.